# How to draw a inner cell?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, photoshop

There is such a picture As in the game [4 photos 1 word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lotum.whatsinthefoto.ru)

[image]

I need to draw cells for letters. I do not remember the name of the style, it seems to me that `Inner`, when the cell is concave inward.

And the fact is that I did not work with `Photoshop` for drawing and use it with `9-Patch`. In the vast Internet did not find (or not properly searched).

So the question is how to draw such a button or cell in `Drawable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Create a custom `drawable` file `bg_rounded_corners.xml` for `rounded` black `box` shape and put this `drawable` into your `res/drawable` folder.

**bg_rounded_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Bottom Shadow -->
    <item>

        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="#2F2F3D" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Top Shadow -->
    <item android:bottom="2dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Center Filled Color -->
    <item
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1.5dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <gradient
                android:startColor="#160A0F"
                android:centerColor="#190B0F"
                android:endColor="#1B0C13"
                android:angle="270"/>

            <corners android:radius="4dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**2.** Design your layout XML using `LinearLayout` with `Horizontal` orientation and put desired number of `TextView` inside this `LinearLayout`. Set custom `drawable` to each `TextView` using attribute `android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners"`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#202531">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="H"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="E"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="L"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="L"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="O"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

FYI, I have used color **`#202531`** as `background` color. For your case, you can use another `color` or use any `image` as background of root `LinearLayout`.

Hope this will help~

Comment: I've tried it. But he could not make a concavity inside, that is, a shadow inside the top, and from below an internal glow

Comment: To `draw` shadow you have to use `<layer-list>` multiple `<shape>`. Check my updated answer. Hope this will meet your requirement. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Very helped!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is here.
Very firstly you have to have this colors defined in your colors.xml in values folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="darkBackground">#13161b</color>
    <color name="silveryBackground">#262d37</color>

</resources>
```

Then you need to create one file in drawable folder say layout_corners_dark.xml and copy this code in this file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/darkBackground"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="0dip"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dip"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip"/>
</shape>
```

Then you need to add button widgets in your activity_main.xml by applying layout_corners_dark.xml to it using `android:background`

and your button xml will be like this

```
  <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="K"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_corners_dark"/>
```

And apply silver background to your activity_main.xml using this line `android:background="@color/silveryBackground"` in your parent layout

Finally your activity_main.xml will look like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/silveryBackground"
    tools:context="com.example.user1.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="K"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_corners_dark"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="H"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_corners_dark"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="N"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_corners_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is screenshot of this layout.
[See output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04jdr.png)

Comment: I've tried it. But he could not make a concavity inside, that is, a shadow inside the top, and from below an internal glow